# Regex: return contents of parentheses unless substring is present inside, then return everything outside parentheses

Tags: python, sql, regex

I have a series of strings that looks like this:

```
str_one = "Coder X.Y. (Something Dogs Do X.Y.)"
str_two = "Something Cats Ignore X.Y. (Coder X.Y.)"
```

I want to be able to extract the contents of the parentheses unless there is a specific substring contained within (let's say "coder"), then I want everything outside the parentheses returned. For the above examples, I want the outputs to look like this:

```
output_str_one = "Something Dogs Do X.Y."
output_str_two = "Something Cats Ignore X.Y."
```

What I have so far is just a catch of substring in the parentheses if a certain word is present:

```
import re
re.findall('\(([^(|)]*Something[^)|(]*)\)', output_str_one)
```

That doesn't work for the second example obviously.

I could just split the string by "(" and then select the resulting string that does not contain the substring 'coder' ie.:

```
str_one_split = re.split("\(|\)", str_one)
str_one_split = list(filter(None, str_one_split))
res = [x for x in str_one_split if "coder" not in x.lower()]
print(res)
>>['Something Dogs Do X.Y.']
```

But really I was hoping for a regex expression so that I can add it to an expression being used in SQL.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Future editors: please do not remove language tags from regex questions. We need them to know what flavor of regex the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an alternation and lookahead assertions:

```bash
(?<=\()(?![^()]*Coder)[^()]+(?=\))|[^(]+(?=\([^()]*Coder)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pe4XqB/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\()(?![^()]*Coder)[^()]+(?=\))`:  Match string inside `(...)` if it doesn't contain `Coder`
- `|`: OR
- `[^(]+(?=\([^()]*Coder)`: Match string before first `(` if we have `Coder` inside the `(...)`

Comment: It did thanks! I'm guessing I could add (?i) to the beginning of the expression and it would ignore case sensitivity correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, just start your regex with `(?i)`